# General Java Style Suggestions - Classification Problem from CodeSprint 2012

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Solution for Quora Classifier question from CodeSprint 2012 This class
 * implements a logistic regression classifier trained with Stochastic Gradient
 * Descent. No regularization is used as it wasn't necessary for this problem
 */
public class QuoraClassifier {

  static boolean debug;
  double[] theta; // regression coefficients
  double[] yTraining; // training targets
  double[][] xTraining; // training predictors
  double[] xMean; // mean of each training predictor
  double[] xVarSqrt; // variance of each training predictor
  double alpha = 5; // training rate
  int numTrainingExamples; // number of training examples
  int numFeatures; // number of features in predictor

  /**
   * Load training data
   *
   * @param sc
   */
  private void loadTrainingData(Scanner sc) {
    String[] trainingDimString = sc.nextLine().split("\\s");
    numTrainingExamples = Integer.parseInt(trainingDimString[0]);
    numFeatures = Integer.parseInt(trainingDimString[1]);
    yTraining = new double[numTrainingExamples];
    xTraining = new double[numTrainingExamples][numFeatures];
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingExamples; i++) {
      String[] trainingPoint = sc.nextLine().split("\\s");
      // read training targets and convert from -1/+1 to 0/1
      yTraining[i] = (Double.parseDouble(trainingPoint[1]) + 1) / 2;
      // read training predictors
      for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
        String featureString = trainingPoint[2 + fIndex];
        xTraining[i][fIndex] = Double.parseDouble(featureString
            .substring(featureString.indexOf(":") + 1));
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Normalize training data by mean and variance
   */
  private void normalizeTrainingData() {
    // calculate mean of each feature
    xMean = new double[numFeatures];
    for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
      double runningSum = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingExamples; i++) {
        runningSum += xTraining[i][fIndex];
      }
      xMean[fIndex] = runningSum / numTrainingExamples;
    }
    // normalize by feature means
    for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingExamples; i++) {
        xTraining[i][fIndex] -= xMean[fIndex];
      }
    }
    // calculate variance of each feature
    xVarSqrt = new double[numFeatures];
    for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
      double runningSum = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingExamples; i++) {
        runningSum += xTraining[i][fIndex] * xTraining[i][fIndex];
      }
      if (runningSum > 0.0) {
        xVarSqrt[fIndex] = Math.sqrt(runningSum / numTrainingExamples);
      } else {
        xVarSqrt[fIndex] = 1.0;
      }
    }
    // normalize by feature variances
    for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingExamples; i++) {
        xTraining[i][fIndex] /= xVarSqrt[fIndex];
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Train logistic regression coefficients
   */
  private void trainLogistic() {
    theta = new double[numFeatures];
    for (int i = 0; i < numTrainingExamples; i++) {
      double yEstimate = classify(xTraining[i]);
      // calculate error in prediction
      double e = yEstimate - yTraining[i];
      for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
        // update regression coefficient
        theta[fIndex] -= alpha / numTrainingExamples * e * xTraining[i][fIndex];
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Classify feature vector x
   *
   * @param x
   *          array of doubles containing the features
   * @return double containing the soft classification
   */
  private double classify(double[] x) {
    double z = 0;
    for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
      double xNormalized = (x[fIndex] - xMean[fIndex]) / xVarSqrt[fIndex];
      z += theta[fIndex] * xNormalized;
    }
    return sigmoid(z);
  }

  /**
   * Run classification for a set of queries and output the result to System.out
   *
   * @param scIn
   *          input data (contains test and training sets)
   * @param scOut
   *          training targets for validation
   */
  private void classifyQueries(Scanner scIn, Scanner scOut) {
    int numQueries = Integer.parseInt(scIn.nextLine());
    double[] xQuery = new double[numFeatures];
    double numMisclassifications = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numQueries; i++) {
      // load query
      String[] queryString = scIn.nextLine().split("\\s");
      String label = queryString[0];
      for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < numFeatures; fIndex++) {
        String featureString = queryString[1 + fIndex];
        xQuery[fIndex] = Double.parseDouble(featureString
            .substring(featureString.indexOf(":") + 1));
      }
      // classify
      double classification = classify(xQuery);
      // output result to System.out
      if (classification > 0.5) {
        System.out.printf("%s +1\n", label);
      } else {
        System.out.printf("%s -1\n", label);
      }
      if (debug) {
        // read training targets
        String[] outString = scOut.nextLine().split("\\s");
        String correctClassification = outString[1];
        // display misclassifications
        if (classification > 0.5) {
          if (correctClassification.equals("-1")) {
            numMisclassifications++;
            System.out.printf("%s +1 %s\n", label, correctClassification);
          }
        } else {
          if (correctClassification.equals("+1")) {
            numMisclassifications++;
            System.out.printf("%s -1 %s\n", label, correctClassification);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (debug) {
      System.out.printf("Misclassification rate: %.1f%%\n",
          (100.0 * numMisclassifications) / numQueries);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sigmoid function
   *
   * @param z
   *          a double
   * @return double containing 1/(1 + exp(-z))
   */
  private double sigmoid(double z) {
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-z));
  }

  /**
   * Run classification using input data from scanner scIn and validate against
   * training targets in scanner scOut
   *
   * @param scIn
   *          input data (contains test and training sets)
   * @param scOut
   *          training targets for validation
   */
  public void run(Scanner scIn, Scanner scOut) {
    loadTrainingData(scIn);
    normalizeTrainingData();
    trainLogistic();
    classifyQueries(scIn, scOut);
  }

  /**
   * Run classification and profile execution time. If no arguments are supplied
   * input is read from standard input and output is written to standard output
   * If two arguments are supplied then input is read from the file specified by
   * the first argument and output is written to the file specified by the
   * second argument
   *
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scIn; // input file
    Scanner scOut; // output file
    if (args.length > 0) { // input stream from file (for testing)
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));
      scIn = new Scanner(in);
      BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[1])));
      scOut = new Scanner(out);
      debug = true;
    } else { // input streamed from System.in (used in competition)
      scIn = new Scanner(System.in);
      scOut = null;
      debug = false;
    }
    long startTime = 0;
    if (debug) {
      startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    // run classification
    QuoraClassifier classifier = new QuoraClassifier();
    classifier.run(scIn, scOut);
    if (debug) {
      long endTime = System.nanoTime();
      System.out.printf("Execution time: %f\n",
          ((double) endTime - (double) startTime) / 1e9);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just off the top of my head:

- In main - what should happen if `args.length == 1` ? Currently, you'll get an exception.
- Your field names are a bit odd - `xTraining` and `yTraining` in particular.  Instead of having these names, and comments about what the variables actually mean, why not just call your variables `regressionCoefficients`, `trainingTargets`, `trainingPredictors` and so on?
- Some of the methods are a bit long.  The fact that your methods mostly have internal comments kind of indicates this.  In my opinion, each method should do just one thing; and that one thing should be explained in a javadoc comment at the top of the method.  No comments at all inside methods.
- Comments should be used to explain things, not just to repeat what's in the code.  For example, your "return" comment at the top of `sigmoid` is pointless.  I suggest removing it.
- Do you really want to use `System.out.printf` for logging?  There are more versatile ways of logging (which you could google), and more readable means of formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as your other [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7813/general-java-style-suggestions-clustering-question-from-codesprint-2012/7841#7841).

You should have some class to load (and contain) the original data; some Normalizer interface (you might have many different classes that implement different normalizations); some Classifier interface; you are training something, so that something should be a class with a train(?,...) method.  And then again, there are probably many ways to train it, so there should be some interface for that too.